# ULS Logs are not being trimmed

Tags: 2016, central-administration, uls

We've configured our ULS Logs to be a maximum of 50GB, via Central Admin => Monitoring => Configure Diagnostic Logging.
When clicking OK at that page, it will trim all logs on all servers to 50GB.
However, over time it will grow to way more than 50GB, e.g. 200GB.

Only when we go back to this page and click OK, it will trim back to 50GB.

I can't find any timer job that is responsible for trimming the ULS Logs. Why isn't this working as expected?

Answer (score 4):

ULS Log deletion is done by SharePoint Tracing Service.

Please check the according Service-Account in Windows-Services console. 
[image]

This user is normally a member of the "WSS_WPG" local group:
[image]

Then make sure this group has the permission to "Delete subfolders and files" on your ULS-Log folder:
[image]

If this doesn't help you can check ULS-Logs for the following string: `Log retention limit reached.`